# Azure Mobile Services username and password custom authentication?

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm currently rewriting an AngularJS application to use Azure Mobile Services for the back end.

Unfortunately I can't find an obvious simple login authentication mechanism that uses a username and password combination.  Ideally the solution would include registration, login, logout and password resets.

As of 24/Oct/2014 this is the [most requested feature](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/216254-mobile-services/suggestions/3313778-custom-user-auth) on the [official Azure Feedback page](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/216254-mobile-services), so I'm not the only one looking (550 and counting).

Can anyone recommend one or know about a possible solution from Microsoft that is in the pipeline?

I don't want to write a custom simple provider, then replace it shortly after...
Both Parse and Firebase have simple authentication providers so I'm sure MS will provide one at some point.

Comment: 0
down vote
Yes I Am Looking for this too. They have login providers for MS, Google, FB, Twitter but none for like simple Password And Username. I want help with this too.

Comment: Sani, well here's hoping it's being written by MS as we speak.  I'm sure the Azure Mobile Services programme manager has got it on his list of todos... I'm thinking I'll give Parse a go as it'll be easier to switch to a new PAAS than implement a secure simple auth including registration, login, forgotten pw, account locking etc.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/) article describes how to create a .net backend in mobile services that uses custom authentication, including registration and log-in

[This](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Exploring_custom_identity_in_Mobile_Services_Day_12_.aspx) one shows the same with JS backend and iOS client

Comment: Yossi, thanks for the links.  In the end I ported my app over to use Meteor JS as I wanted a platform that had this built in and also straight forward realtime data.  When Microsoft comes out with a built in one I'll give it a try.